# Flutter web app not showing typed password when set to show password

Tags: flutter, web, passwords

On my flutter webapp I am trying to show the password if the user chose to show it.  If I set my bool value to false it start by showing the normal text and then if I press the button to show or hide the password it will obscure the text but it will not un-obscure the text.  I added a print function in one of my try's and it does change the bool value from false to true and back to false.  I have it it a setState but no luck.  I tryied many different examples online but can not get it to work with the web app.

The code

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
c_width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.8;
return Scaffold(
appBar: AppBar(title: Text("App"),
),
body: signUpWidget(widget.signUpValue),
);
}

Widget signUpWidget(String? rl)  {
switch(rl) {
case 'User': {
return SingleChildScrollView(
child: Container (
width: c_width,
padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),

child: Column(
child: Column(
children: <Widget>[



TextFormField(
obscureText: isObscure,
decoration: InputDecoration(
suffix: TextButton(
child: isPasswordObscure
? Text(
'Show',
style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
)

: Text(
'Hide',
style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
),
onPressed: () {
setState(() { 
isObscure = !isObscure; 
isPasswordObscure = !isObscure;
});
},
),
),
```

),

Like I say it changes the text to hide and show and if I print the bool value it changes from true to false, but it does not unObscure the text in the field to show the password.  Is it something to do with web?  or am I missing something?

Thank you.

Comment: can you include from build method

Comment: Ok, but not much in there , will go slow to load the code for I am blind struggle to get always the spacing to accept it on here.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you dont need to have two bool,

```dart
TextFormField(
  obscureText: isObscure,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    suffix: TextButton(
      child: isObscure //< using 
          ? Text(
              'Show',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
            )
          : Text(
              'Hide',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
            ),
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          isObscure = !isObscure;
          // isPasswordObscure = !isObscure; // here it reverse the variable isPasswordObscure 
        });
      },
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: or you may just want `isPasswordObscure =  isObscure;` because it reverse top

Answer (score 0):

It might be occurring due to this problem in `setState((){})`.

```
setState(() { 
 // assume isObscure is true initially
 isObscure = !isObscure; 
 // now isObscure is false
 isPasswordObscure = !isObscure;
 // now isPasswordObscure is true, because isObscure's value has already changed.
});
```

To solve this, first save isObscure to a temporary variable.

```
setState(() { 
 var temp = isObscure;
 isObscure = !temp; 
 isPasswordObscure = !temp;
});
```

Or,

Entirely avoid using two bools.

```
setState(() { 
 isObscure = !isObscure; 
});
```

---

It seems like this occurs only in web.

Follow these steps to fix this,

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/83695#issuecomment-1083537482

Or

Upgrade to the latest `Flutter` version.

Comment: Ok, that is only one fo the examples I used.  The thing is it changes the bool values like it should, but it does not rebuild the text controller or tex field with the shown password,  say forinstance I make password 1234, if i change to hide it give ****, but when it should show 1234 again it keeps showing ***.  Thanks